# RFID-RC522 not working properly?

Tags: arduino-nano, rfid, rf

So I'm working with an arduino uno and I want to read the UID from one card and write it to another with the code of Miguel Balboa but the RC522 doesn't appear to read anything on the serial monitor. However, if I the one below, it actually reads everything. I've also used the hardware checker and it says that everything is working fine. What am I doing wrong or what do I have to do to clone the UID with this code? Thank you very much in advance.

````
#include <SPI.h>

#define SAD 10
#define RST 5

MFRC522 nfc(SAD, RST);

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  // Read a fast as possible. There is a limit for how long we are
  // allowed to read from the tags.
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Looking for MFRC522.");
  nfc.begin();

  // Get the firmware version of the RFID chip
  byte version = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! version) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find MFRC522 board.");
    while(1); //halt
  }

  Serial.print("Found chip MFRC522 ");
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. 0x");
  Serial.print(version, HEX);
  Serial.println(".");
}

byte keyA[6] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, };
byte keyB[6] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, };

void loop() {
  byte status;
  byte data[MAX_LEN];
  byte serial[5];
  int i, j, pos;

  // Send a general request out into the aether. If there is a tag in
  // the area it will respond and the status will be MI_OK.
  status = nfc.requestTag(MF1_REQIDL, data);

  if (status == MI_OK) {
    Serial.println("Tag detected.");
    Serial.print("Type: ");
    Serial.print(data[0], HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(data[1], HEX);

    // calculate the anti-collision value for the currently detected
    // tag and write the serial into the data array.
    status = nfc.antiCollision(data);
    memcpy(serial, data, 5);

    Serial.println("The serial nb of the tag is:");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Serial.print(serial[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
    Serial.println(serial[3], HEX);

    // Select the tag that we want to talk to. If we don't do this the
    // chip does not know which tag it should talk if there should be
    // any other tags in the area..
    nfc.selectTag(serial);

    // Assuming that there are only 64 blocks of memory in this chip.
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      // Try to authenticate each block first with the A key.
      status = nfc.authenticate(MF1_AUTHENT1A, i, keyA, serial);
      if (status == MI_OK) {
        Serial.print("Authenticated block nb. 0x");
        Serial.print(i, HEX);
        Serial.println(" with key A.");
        // Reading block i from the tag into data.
        status = nfc.readFromTag(i, data);
        if (status == MI_OK) {
          // If there was no error when reading; print all the hex
          // values in the data.
          for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
            Serial.print(", ");
          }
          Serial.println(data[15], HEX);
        } else {
          Serial.println("Read failed.");
        }
      } else {
        // If we could not authenticate with the A key, we will try
        // the B key.
        status = nfc.authenticate(MF1_AUTHENT1B, i, keyB, serial);
        if (status == MI_OK) {
          Serial.print("Authenticated block nb. 0x");
          Serial.print(i, HEX);
          Serial.println(" with key B.");
          status = nfc.readFromTag(i, data);
          if (status == MI_OK) {
            for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
              Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
              Serial.print(", ");
            }
            Serial.println(data[15], HEX);
          } else {
            Serial.println("Read failed.");
          }
        } else {
          Serial.print("Access denied at block nb. 0x");
          Serial.println(i, HEX);
        }
      }
    }

    // Stop the tag and get ready for reading a new tag.
    nfc.haltTag();
  }
  delay(2000);
}```
````

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong ... it appears that there is no code for writing to a card

Comment: that's the code that i'm using instead of the one from Miguel Balboa, which doesn't work. I was asking for a code to actually write a card with the code i've given